# Shared albums FB Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As you know FB has a feature - shared albums. It is pretty good feature which allow many users to use one album.

Issue: I try to develop an iOS application which just show all photos from this **SHARED** album, but I get only MY photos (which I uploaded), not all. Is there way to get all photos, not only my?

Example: I created a **shared** album, uploaded 7 photos. My friend uploaded 2 photos. I tried to check this photos with FB Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and I see only 7 photos in this album and my friend see only 2 photos.

PS: album permissions - for everyone